# Using combo box values with a button

Tags: java, swing, button, combobox, controller

I have 10 combo boxes and one button. Is there an easy way to make it so you set all the values of each combo box and then press this button and it stores all the values of the combo boxes?

Answer (score 0):

You first have to iterate through all your `JComboBox` elements and get their selected state (ie: `getSelectedItem()` or `getSelectedIndex()`). Once you have determined what selection has been made, you can save the selections in a number of places to be read later, dependent on your needs:

1. You can save the states into a file that can be read at a later date
2. You can save the information in the local registry via [Java Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html)
3. If it is a network application, you can save the information in an SQL database

Comment: I have 10 combo boxes, will this mean that I need 10 controllers? They all do the same thing.

Comment: You can use a loop to create new `JComboBox` elements dynamically while attaching the same model to each one so that they display the same combo box choices. When saving the selections, save and restore them in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! I'd propose to write yourself a new class which has both things:

```
class comboTrack{
private JComboBox box;
private Object value;

public comboTrack(JComboBox box){
    this.box = box;
    this.value = box.getSelectedItem();
}

public void update(){
    this.value = box.getSelectedItem();
}
public Object getValue(){
    return value;
}
}
```

Then, use these instead of normal Boxes. Like this:

```
//List of boxes (class variable):
    ArrayList<comboTrack> boxes;

    //Inside the button click method:
    for(comboTrack box : boxes){
        box.update();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ComboBoxValues extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    JComboBox comboBox;
    JComboBox comboBox_1;
    JComboBox comboBox_2;
    JComboBox comboBox_3;
    JComboBox comboBox_4;
    JComboBox comboBox_5;
    JComboBox comboBox_6;
    JComboBox comboBox_7;
    JComboBox comboBox_8;
    JComboBox comboBox_9;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ComboBoxValues frame = new ComboBoxValues();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public ComboBoxValues() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_comboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox.gridx = 0;
        gbc_comboBox.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(comboBox, gbc_comboBox);

        comboBox.addItem("comboBox_0 val 1");
        comboBox.addItem("comboBox_0 val 2");

        comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_comboBox_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox_1.gridx = 1;
        gbc_comboBox_1.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(comboBox_1, gbc_comboBox_1);

        comboBox_1.addItem("comboBox_1 val 1");
        comboBox_1.addItem("comboBox_1 val 2");

        comboBox_2 = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_comboBox_2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox_2.gridx = 0;
        gbc_comboBox_2.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(comboBox_2, gbc_comboBox_2);

        comboBox_2.addItem("comboBox_2 val 1");
        comboBox_2.addItem("comboBox_2 val 2");

        comboBox_3 = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox_3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox_3.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_comboBox_3.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox_3.gridx = 1;
        gbc_comboBox_3.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(comboBox_3, gbc_comboBox_3);

        comboBox_3.addItem("comboBox_3 val 1");
        comboBox_3.addItem("comboBox_3 val 2");

        comboBox_4 = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox_4 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox_4.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_comboBox_4.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox_4.gridx = 0;
        gbc_comboBox_4.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(comboBox_4, gbc_comboBox_4);

        comboBox_4.addItem("comboBox_4 val 1");
        comboBox_4.addItem("comboBox_4 val 2");

        comboBox_5 = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox_5 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox_5.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_comboBox_5.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox_5.gridx = 1;
        gbc_comboBox_5.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(comboBox_5, gbc_comboBox_5);

        comboBox_5.addItem("comboBox_5 val 1");
        comboBox_5.addItem("comboBox_5 val 2");

        comboBox_6 = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox_6 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox_6.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_comboBox_6.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox_6.gridx = 0;
        gbc_comboBox_6.gridy = 3;
        contentPane.add(comboBox_6, gbc_comboBox_6);

        comboBox_6.addItem("comboBox_6 val 1");
        comboBox_6.addItem("comboBox_6 val 2");

        comboBox_7 = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox_7 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox_7.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_comboBox_7.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox_7.gridx = 1;
        gbc_comboBox_7.gridy = 3;
        contentPane.add(comboBox_7, gbc_comboBox_7);

        comboBox_7.addItem("comboBox_7 val 1");
        comboBox_7.addItem("comboBox_7 val 2");

        comboBox_8 = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox_8 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox_8.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_comboBox_8.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox_8.gridx = 0;
        gbc_comboBox_8.gridy = 4;
        contentPane.add(comboBox_8, gbc_comboBox_8);

        comboBox_8.addItem("comboBox_8 val 1");
        comboBox_8.addItem("comboBox_8 val 2");

        comboBox_9 = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox_9 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox_9.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_comboBox_9.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox_9.gridx = 1;
        gbc_comboBox_9.gridy = 4;
        contentPane.add(comboBox_9, gbc_comboBox_9);

        comboBox_9.addItem("comboBox_9 val 1");
        comboBox_9.addItem("comboBox_9 val 2");

        JButton btnGetValues = new JButton("Get Values");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnGetValues = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnGetValues.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_btnGetValues.gridx = 1;
        gbc_btnGetValues.gridy = 5;
        contentPane.add(btnGetValues, gbc_btnGetValues);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 6;
        contentPane.add(textArea, gbc_lblNewLabel);
        textArea.setColumns(30);
        textArea.setRows(5);



        pack();

        btnGetValues.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                textArea.setText(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()+","+
                        comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString()+","+
                        comboBox_2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\n"+
                        comboBox_3.getSelectedItem().toString()+","+
                        comboBox_4.getSelectedItem().toString()+","+
                        comboBox_5.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\n"+
                        comboBox_6.getSelectedItem().toString()+","+
                        comboBox_7.getSelectedItem().toString()+","+
                        comboBox_8.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\n"+
                        comboBox_9.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```